# npm ERR! when doing a npm install for discord bot

Tags: javascript, npm-install

Im pretty new to the coding world of javascript, and I wanted to try it out and make a discord bot. When I ran npm install a bunch or errors popped up and Im quite clueless on how to solve this issue.

Error:

[image]

Code for *package.json*:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Oh sorry my bad turns out the codes I sourced from were in itallic font and thus the system couldnt read the program, I typed out the codes manually and everything runs fine now.